# What is the general rule of using `> foo.txt` and `< foo.txt` all by itself in bash and zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection

They are not valid in `csh`. What is the general rule of using them in `bash` and `zsh`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash, redirections without a command just perform the redirections and then close them:

- `< foo.txt` by itself as a command line will open the file `foo.txt` for reading and then close it.
- `> foo.txt` will open the file `foo.txt` for writing, creating it if necessary and truncating it, and then close it. Quick way to empty a file.

With zsh, redirections without a command run `NULLCMD` or `READNULLCMD`.

- `READNULLCMD` (or `NULLCMD`, if `READNULLCMD is unset) for redirections of stdin:

  ```
  % echo foo > foo.txt
  % READNULLCMD=nl
  % < foo.txt
       1  foo
  ```
- `NULLCMD` for redirections of stdout:

  ```
  % NULLCMD='ls'
  % > foo.txt   # runs $NULLCMD
  % < foo.txt   # runs $READNULLCMD, showing the output of `NULLCMD` run previously
       1  Applications
       2  Desktop
       3  Documents
       4  Downloads
  ```

See [Zsh 7.3, Redirections with no command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirections-with-no-command) for details:

> When a simple command consists of one or more redirection operators
>   and zero or more parameter assignments, but no command name, zsh can
>   behave in several ways.
>
> If the parameter `NULLCMD` is not set or the option `CSH_NULLCMD` is
>   set, an error is caused. This is the *csh* behavior and `CSH_NULLCMD`
>   is set by default when emulating *csh*.
>
> If the option `SH_NULLCMD` is set, the builtin `:` is inserted as a
>   command with the given redirections. This is the default when
>   emulating *sh* or *ksh*.
>
> Otherwise, if the parameter `NULLCMD` is set, its value will be used
>   as a command with the given redirections. If both `NULLCMD` and
>   `READNULLCMD` are set, then the value of the latter will be used
>   instead of that of the former when the redirection is an input. The
>   default for `NULLCMD` is ‘`cat`’ and for `READNULLCMD` is ‘`more`’.
>   Thus
>
> ```
> < file
> ```
>
> shows the contents of file on standard output, with paging if that is
>   a terminal. `NULLCMD` and `READNULLCMD` may refer to shell functions.

Comment: @Kusalananda still the same in both cases, I'd think. With `>foo.txt` and input already redirected, `bash` will create/open/truncate `foo.txt`, close it, and zsh will, using default `NULLCMD` `cat`, write all the input to `foo.txt`. I don't think either shell changes behaviour for this particular action when running as a script vs running interactively.

Comment: Yes, you covered all bases. I was just a lazy reader. Thanks, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: In any case, this is non-standard behavior and `zsh` will typically just complain caused by own bugs if you e.g. call `< /etc/passwd` as it tries to run `PAGER` in a broken way. Note that `PAGER` is typically something like `more -s` and `zsh` complains with `zsh: command not found: more -s`